# Problem with direct uploads in Rails 6 ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am getting the following erroor when trying to use the direct upload functionality of ActiveStorage.  I have searched for the error `unexpected value at params[:whitelist_headers]`, and the only results that I found suggested to upgrade to the latest version of `aws-sdk-s3`. However, I believe that I am using the latest version of s3.  Here is my Gemfile:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby File.read(File.join(__dir__, ".ruby-version")).chomp

gem "rails", "~> 6.0"
gem "rails-i18n"

gem "bootsnap", require: false
gem "foreman"
gem "pg"
gem "puma", "~> 4.3"
...
...
...

gem 'aws-sdk-s3', require: false
gem 'mini_magick'

gem 'rack-cors
```

And the error message:

```
Started POST "/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-10-12 17:14:51 -0500
Processing by ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"blob"=>{"filename"=>"Screen Shot 2020-10-02 at 4.02.49 PM.png", "content_type"=>"image/png", "byte_size"=>120011, "checksum"=>"06QCMFP69Z4HT6w98ugkyQ=="}, "direct_upload"=>{"blob"=>{"filename"=>"Screen Shot 2020-10-02 at 4.02.49 PM.png", "content_type"=>"image/png", "byte_size"=>120011, "checksum"=>"06QCMFP69Z4HT6w98ugkyQ=="}}}
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ActiveStorage::Blob Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "ai7p1m5pknvo2wstwc6nw8ihf31h"], ["filename", "Screen Shot 2020-10-02 at 4.02.49 PM.png"], ["content_type", "image/png"], ["byte_size", 120011], ["checksum", "06QCMFP69Z4HT6w98ugkyQ=="], ["created_at", "2020-10-12 22:14:51.332510"]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
  S3 Storage (0.8ms) Generated URL for file at key: ai7p1m5pknvo2wstwc6nw8ihf31h ()
Completed 500  in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms | Allocations: 6659)

ArgumentError (unexpected value at params[:whitelist_headers]):

aws-sdk-core (3.46.2) lib/aws-sdk-core/param_validator.rb:32:in `validate!'
aws-sdk-core (3.46.2) lib/aws-sdk-core/param_validator.rb:13:in `validate!'
aws-sdk-core (3.46.2) lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_validator.rb:23:in `call'
aws-sdk-core (3.46.2) lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:14:in `call'
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65363510/1254808) this, but based on an assumption that what happened to you happened to me as well. To clear that assumption, you could provide your `Gemfile.lock`. I guess you no longer have it, but it’s as important as the log and the `Gemfile`, because none of the two show the exact version of Rails gems and `aws-sdk-s3` gem.

Answer (score 2):

I run into similar issue with one older Ruby on Rails app. The issue in my case was that the `aws-sdk-s3` gem introduced the `whitelist_headers` option in version 1.48.0 released on 30 Aug 2019. Rails 6 started using this option in version 6.0.3.1 released on 6 May 2020. Because Active Storage gem does not specify AWS SDK as its dependency, it’s quite possible you updated Active Storage while leaving AWS SDK behind (happened to me).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by replacing `gem 'aws-sdk-s3'` with `gem 'aws-sdk'` in my Gemfile.

This may not be an ideal solution, as the [docs](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) state the following:

> Alternatively, the aws-sdk gem contains every available AWS service gem. This gem is very large; it is recommended to use it only as a quick way to migrate from V2 or if you depend on many AWS services.

Comment: You probably solved not because of using `aws-sdk` gem instead of `aws-sdk-s3` but simply because you updated the SDK. I’m sure just updating the `aws-sdk-s3` would solved too. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65363510/1254808).